# Get range-v3 intersection of vector of pairs

Tags: c++, c++17, range-v3

I want to get an intersection of two vectors of pairs. I can do it with the stl which uses the default comparator (? - correct me if I word it wrong).

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> pathWire1 = {{1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3}};
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> pathWire2 = { {2,2}, {0,0}};
std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> res;

std::sort(pathWire1.begin(), pathWire1.end());
std::sort(pathWire2.begin(), pathWire2.end());
std::set_intersection(pathWire1.begin(), pathWire1.end(),
                        pathWire2.begin(), pathWire2.end(),
                        std::back_inserter(res));

//res contains {2,2}
```

At best I wanted to do it with ranges:

```
ranges::sort(pathWire1);
ranges::sort(pathWire2);
ranges::view::set_intersection(pathWire1, pathWire2);
//ranges::view::set_intersection(pathWire1, pathWire2, std::back_inserter(res);
```

I tried to follow this [documentation](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/group__group-algorithms.html#ga16ff3992a9314dcf174835b3a6e05245) however I cannot get it to compile, because the template fails to specialize:

```
error C2672: 'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found
```

Do I need to provide custom comparator? I had problems with compiling `ranges::sort` as well. Is it because `std::vector` is specialized for non-trivial type `std::pair`?

Comment: If you want eager evaluation do not use a view: https://wandbox.org/permlink/36hqDjXRU1dp4kuS

Comment: [Why does ranges not support std::back_inserter?](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/issues/867)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ranges::view::set_intersection` returns the result as a new range (in this case, a new view). See the [tests](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/test/view/set_intersection.cpp) how to use that functionality.

Example:

```
using IntPair = std::pair<int,int>;
using IntPairVector = std::vector<IntPair>;

IntPairVector pathWire1 = {{1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3}};
IntPairVector pathWire2 = { {2,2}, {0,0}};

ranges::sort(pathWire1);
ranges::sort(pathWire2);
auto res = ranges::view::set_intersection(pathWire1, pathWire2);

for(auto&& p : res)
    std::cout << p.first << ' ' << p.second << '\n';

// prints 2 2
```

#### [LIVE DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/GMkkJE)

Comment: The provided example works with wandbox and other online compilers. However on my local build I am using ranges-v3 0.9.1 and I still cannot compile it. I build under Windows using MSVC Version 19.23.28107. Any tips to that?

Comment: See this blog post for MSVC: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/use-the-official-range-v3-with-msvc-2017-version-15-9/. In short, use `vcpkg` to install `range-v3` since some modifications need to be made in order to be compilable with MSVC.